# Help on proof of derivative equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm in need of help to proof an equation. I define $\lambda(z) = \dfrac{e^z}{(1 + e^z)}.\;$ 
Now I need to prove $\lambda'(z) = \lambda(z) [1 - \lambda(z)]$

Any help?

Comment: What have you tried? How do you calculate $\lambda'(z)$? This seems like a straightforward application of the quotient rule.

Comment: It might be of help to write $\lambda(z)$ as $1 - \dfrac1{1+e^z}$ while differentiating.

Comment: You could also use a shortcut by observing that $\frac{e^z}{(1 + e^z)} = (1+e^{-z})^{-1}$ and using the chain rule.

Comment: Maybe implicitly differentiate the equation $\lambda(z)(1+e^z) =e^z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use logarithmic differentiation:
$(\ln f)' = f'/f$
or $f' = f (\ln f)'$.

Letting $f(z) = e^z/(1+e^z)$,
$\ln f(z) = z - \ln(1+e^z)$
so
$(\ln f(z))' = 1 - e^z/(1+e^z) = 1-f(z)$
(by an $amazing$ coincidence).

Without doing anything else.
$f'(z)/f(z) = 1-f(z)$,
and this is what you want.

When you want to differentiate 
a function which is built by multiplying, dividing,
and raising expressions to powers,
this technique can be very useful.
Just remember $(\ln f)' = f'/f$
or $f' = f(\ln f)'$.

Comment: +1 Nice, elegant proof with the logarithmic differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

For all the talk of shortcuts thus far, I think this problem is most easily solved by just doing the obvious thing: $\lambda(z)$ is defined as a quotient, so we use the quotient rule.

Recall the quotient rule:$\left(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right)' = \frac{(g(z)f'(z) - f(z)g'(z)}{g(z)^2}$. In this case, that translates with $f(z) = e^z$ and $g(z) = 1 + e^z$. So we get $\lambda'(z) = \frac{(1+e^z)(e^z) - (e^z)(e^z)}{(1+e^z)^2}$, and the rest amounts to recognizing where $\lambda(z)$ is in this expression.

Hope that's helpful!